# how to manipulate Jquery ajax autocomplete URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery ajax autocomplete plugin and was wondering how do i add more parameters to the query string of autocomplete? It auto generates one, but i'd like to add a parameter to it.  How do i do that?

Comment: A quick look in documentation I could find that you can pass URL with query parameter to the source option in autocomplete.

Comment: for some reason it's accepting paraments, just the rest of the urls...